# Причина ошибки в C#

Tags: c#

Пишу

```
label1 -> Text = "Hello World!";
```

Выводится ошибка, что:
К указателю должен быть применен оператор "*" или "->"
Как исправить?

Comment: Эээ, ну С++ переходит в С#???? Прикольно  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка у вас в синтаксисе потому что:

```
Label1.Text="Hello, World!";
```

Так правильно

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqC5GKr6yDY 5:27. Там он так написал и все правильно и никакой ошибки. Так в чем проблема тогда???

Comment: Там самую малость другой язык программирования: не **C#**, а **C++**

Comment: аа, ясно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

Не бывает простых вопросов....

1)С# нужно обращаться к полям и методам класса через точку.

2)В С# есть возможность включить в настройках проекта небезопасный код. Он предполагает обращение при помощи * или -> по указателям, но также только в отдельных случаях (к массивам и областям памяти).

Comment: спасибо за инфо!